# 403 ошибка на http://site.ru/index.php

Tags: joomla

Сайт сейчас доступен по https:// и возвращает 403 ошибку по http://. Хорошо было бы поставить редирект с http://, но не могу, так как стоит 403 ошибка. Пробовал ставить [редиректы с рег.ру](https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/sajty-i-domeny/kak-dobavit-redirekt/redirekt-s-http-na-https).

Не знаю даже какую информацию необходимо написать для решения вопроса.
В configuration.php такие настройки:

```
public $force_ssl = '0';
public $live_site = 'https://site.ru/';
```

В .htaccess никаких настроек подобных нет (пробовал его удалять с сервера — ошибка остаётся).

Думаю, предоставленной информации будет крайне мало, чтоб решить проблему, что ещё показывать — пока не пойму, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Установлены модули: sh404SEF и joomshopping. Конфигурация: mysql 5.5.43-37.2, php 5.6.22, Joomla! 3.4.8 Stable, Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable. Вероятно, есть модифицированное ядро, наверняка не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 95 % случаев 403 ошибка — по инициативе хостинга. Спрашивайте поддержку. У меня та же ситуация.